# Migrating from Raspbian to Ubuntu Core & Snaps

Tags: upgrade, snap, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

We are investigating moving an IoT device that currently runs on Raspbian on RaspberryPi over to Ubuntu Core and Snaps.

There are a number of devices already in the field in disparate locations and we're trying to establish what the upgrade path for these might be. Note it is not trivial to just replace SD cards in the devices. We do have access to each device over SSH. The existing 16Gb SD cards also have plenty of space, so a solution that involves partitioning the SD cards may work.

I know it's possible to switch from Stretch -> Buster, but can you switch from Raspbian -> Ubuntu Core easily just over SSH? How would you go about this?

Answer (score 0):

That sort of upgrade is generally not supported.  The only similar method I have seen in the wild even describe was documentation for [replacing non-Alpine Linux with Alpine Linux remotely](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Replacing_non-Alpine_Linux_with_Alpine_remotely) and that was full of caveats and warnings as it looks fairly easy to destroy a disk through those means.  Without direct physical access to the devices you can [install and use snaps on them using Raspbian already](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-raspbian).

The safest option would be to get physical access and make the upgrade directly whether it is through providing an upgrade kit or making on-premises visits to customers.